# How can I change from the interpreter a variable value which is contained in a module of a python project?

Tags: python

Say I have a project with a main.py file like this

```
from pyFiles.module1 import v
from pyFiles.module1 import myClass1
from pyFiles.module2 import myClass2

def main():
    #main function
    print("start up!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

a folder "pyFiles" with an **init**.py file and two modules:

module1.py:

```
x = 2

class myClass1():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.a = a + x
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    def method1(self):
    return self.a + self.b + self.c
```

module2.py

```
from .module1 import myClass1

class myClass2(myClass1):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    super().__init__(a, b, c)
    self.a = 2*a
    self.b = 2*b
    self.c = 2*c
    def method2(self):
    return self.a * self.b*self.b
```

the issue I have is about that x in module1.py, which I want it to be changeble from the user from the interpreter in manner like this os symilar:

once the user type

```
x = 12
```

than that x is going to be changed for ALL modules from 2 to 12. How can I do it?

Comment: You need to import `x` from `module1`. `from module1 import myClass1, x`

Comment: Just import module1 and set x for it `module1.x  = <user's input way>`. Also your `super().__init__(a, b, c)` does not do much, because you override your variables after with ones you passed to init (so your's `a` variable for class2 is not affected by `x` in any way)

Answer (score 0):

To accept user input and assign the value to x, In module1.py use this:
`x = int(input('Enter the value of x: '))`

To make the variable x available in module2.py, you have to import it from module1.py. Use this:

```
import module1
module1.x = int(input('Enter the value of x: '))
```

Hope this answers your question.